# why Length of values (0) does not match length of index (1913)?

Tags: python

Assuming that my csv file has the following dataset column 'postal' filled with thousands of 6 digit. [E.g. 423524, 643231, 467278].

How do I return the first 2 digit of the dataset number and label it on a new column? For instance, in the new column, if the first 2 number is 42, label it as A.

I realized that doing str matching may not be ideal. Will need some advice.

When I tried coding it this way, it shows a ValueError.

```
def postalcode (x): 
    result = []
    for i in x: 
        if 1 - 46 or 58:
            central_region
        elif 46 - 52:
            east_region
        elif 53 - 55 or 57 or 77 - 80 or 82:
            northeast_region
        elif 59 - 72:
            west_region
        elif 72 or 73 or 75 or 76:
            north_region
        else:
            break
    return result

kindergarden['postal_code'] = postalcode(kindergarden['postal_code'])
kindergarden.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check not some arithmetical expressions, but properties of code. The following will check first 2 digits of 6-digit postal code and return string label (sorry, I'm too lazy to retype whole strings, so only short version is present). Then it appends new column 'Code_upd' to dataframe with this values.

```
def postal_code(x):
    d = x//10000
    if d in range(1,47) or d==58:
        return 'central'
    elif d in range(46,53):
        return 'east'
    elif d in {53,54,55,57}:
        return 'northeast'
    elif d in range(59,73):
        return 'west'
    elif d in {72,73,75,76}:
        return 'north'
    else:
        return None

kindergarden['Code_upd'] = kindergarden['postal'].map(postal_code)
```

Comment: just curious, why are you using sets instead of lists/tuples ?

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate this a lot and the effort to type it out

Comment: @DevLounge, there was somewhere on SO discussion about that, but can't find it fast. I prefer using sets in such cases, because they have approx. O(1) average complexity for test 'elem in set', when lists or tuples have O(length) average complexity. It doesn't matter for 1,2 or 5 elems, but if we have some previously collected long sets, it can improve performance a little.